# Returning List of MySqlDataAdapter through WCF Service causes error

Tags: c#, mysql, wcf

So I am developing a client-server application that utilizes a `MySQL` database and reads/ writes to it. Everything is running just fine until I add the following method to the `interface` of my `WCF Service`.

```
[OperationContract]
List<MySqlDataAdapter> ShowTables();
```

When this is added to the service contract, the scvutil.exe will fail and state that the server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.

Now I've read this question: [Issue while returning Dataset through WCF Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9207233/issue-while-returning-dataset-through-wcf-service) and I'm curious as to how closely it relates to my question. I understand that returning a `DataSet` is not the route to go, but what exactly is causing this error and what would an advisable alternative for returning this information to a client?

Thank you for your time, consideration, and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, the converter is most likely unable to successfully convert the MySqlDataAdapter into a proper (horribly obtuse) XML object. Even if it could you wouldn't want to use it, the performance hit to processing the data wouldn't scale (and probably not perform to an acceptable standard), can't be used by anything other than .NET and would directly tie your UI layer to a database object and it's implementation. It's just not a good start with WCF.

I'm not sure what kind of data is coming back in ShowTables, but the best alternative would be to create an entity that you can convert the data in the MySqlDataAdapter into that can be properly serialized for use by the client.

For example:

If you have simple table data:

```
TableEntity : BaseEntity
{

    string TableName { get; set; }

    List<TableDataEntity> Data { get; set; }

    TableEntity(MySqlDataAdapter dataAdapter)
    {
        //convert dataAdapter into TableEntity properties
    }
}
```

BaseEntity is optional, just allows for common properties. Your operation would change to:

```
[OperationContract]
List<TableEntity> ShowTables();
```

If the above sounds like more work than you need, I would determine if you NEED WCF.

Answer (score 1):

firstly to answer your question I would say it is probably generating an error because MySqlDataAdapter is not serializable and/or it is contained in an external library.  With regards to that question about a DataSet it's possible that the same applies, a data adapter is more of a wrapper around some data than an object containing the data itself - however, I read that question you posted and they seemed to suggest WCF will still allow you to return a DataSet, it's just very bad practise.

The best thing to do by a long way is something along the lines of Jay's answer.  Your WCF service is acting as the middle-man between your data layer and your application logic, so let it be in charge of reading the DataAdapter and converting the input into a nice set of slimline classes - which can then be serialized by WCF and passed back to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Have u added DataContract attribute to **MySqlDataAdapter** and DataMember attribute to every property in the class MySqlDataAdapter, because WCF works on DataContractSerialization and it needs some additional attributes.